# WordPress anchor click JavaScript open details

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a WooCommerce webshop where I put unique href anchors next to product variation label:

Down the page is a HTML (details and summary) that I want to open when the corresponding anchor is clicked. I don't want to use an onclick in the href.

```
(html above) 
<a class="extra_label" id="lunch" href="#anchor">i</a>

(html below) 
<details id="det">
    <summary><a class="leesmeer">Uitgebreide Lunch</a></summary>
    blablabla
</details>
```

I have included the html ID's and JavaScript:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("lunch").addEventListener("click", displayopen);

    function displayopen() {
        document.getElementById("det").open = true;
    }
</script>
```

but so far it's not working.

Comment: What is the JS console error?

Comment: Good point: typeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

Your show element seems wrong. if you want to show element you should use:
`document.getElementById("det").style.display = 'block';` and to hide it:
`document.getElementById("det").style.display = 'none';`

Or you can use classes to indicate hide/show state.

Comment: Unfortunately it is about a html details that needs to be opened on click. Therefore the attribute open has to be added to details. But I see in the console the error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

sorry, turned out i needed to enqueue the script properly, I echoed it in the header but that is bad practice and not working either... Thanks anyway!